# How to implement OneSignal push notification that opens URL in webview rather than browser?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, onesignal

How to open url in webview when onesignal push notification is send, right now it opens in the default browser and how to handle the target url by using notification handler. Here is the sample code where I want to implement onesignal notification and I tried my level best could not handle with it. Any suggestion from experts.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
}
```

handling

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation... I added this code in my Application class `onCreate()`

```
OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

                String launchURL = result.notification.payload.launchURL;

                if (launchURL != null) {
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Launch URL: " + launchURL);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("url", launchURL);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Launch URL not found");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }).init();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you should set your url as an additional data field instead of as a Launch URL.

Next, using the OneSignal Android [NotificationReceivedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationreceivedhandler-) you can retrieve this additional data and open a webview to the URL.

Comment: Gdeglin, thanks We read the documentation  before itself, what is the problem is that we don't get any exact documentation or example, So it very complex for as to implement the particular feature of one-signal in to our.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create two types of messages, one to send to browsers and another one to the apps.
This question has one example of how this can be done:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/variable-launchurl/

Not sure if it will help your case but I hope so.